# Column specification using >{\cmd} and <{\cmd} examples needed

Tags: tables, tabularx, xltabular

I was reading wikibooks Table tutorial it mentions

**Column specification using >{\cmd} and <{\cmd}**

> The column specification can be altered using the array package. This
> is done in the argument of the tabular environment using >{\command}
> for commands executed right before each column element and <{\command}
> for commands to be executed right after each column element. As an
> example: to get a column in math mode enter:
> \begin{tabular}{>{$}c<{$}}. Another example is changing the font:
> \begin{tabular}{>{\small}c} to print the column in a small font.
>
> The argument of the > and < specifications must be correctly balanced
> when it comes to { and } characters. This means that >{\bfseries} is
> valid, while >{\textbf} will not work and >{\textbf{} is not valid. If
> there is the need to use the text of the table as an argument (for
> instance, using the \textbf to produce bold text), one should use the
> \bgroup and \egroup commands: >{\textbf\bgroup}c<{\egroup} produces
> the intended effect. This works only for some basic LaTeX commands.
> For other commands, such as \underline to underline text, it is
> necessary to temporarily store the column text in a box using lrbox.
> First, you must define such a box with \newsavebox{\boxname} and then
> you can define:

I also read tabularx documentation given here http://ctan.imsc.res.in/macros/latex/required/tools/tabularx.pdf

I am not able to understand  the meaning of

> The argument of the > and < specifications must be correctly balanced
> when it comes to { and } characters.

also it says

> This means that >{\bfseries} is valid, while >{\textbf} will not work
> and >{\textbf{} is not valid. If there is the need to use the text of
> the table as an argument (for instance, using the \textbf to produce
> bold text), one should use the \bgroup and \egroup commands:
>
> > {\textbf\bgroup}c<{\egroup} produces the intended effect.

so I want to know why is >{\bfseries} is valid and >{\textbf} will not work.

I am not able to understand the meaning of these sentences in documentation is there
any example for this.

Comment: `\textbf` is acommand that takes an argument (example: `\textbf{bold text}`) while `\bfseries` is a switch. (example `\bfseries bold text`). `\bfseries` is active inside of a group or untill switched back, `\textbf` only makes the contents of its argument bold.

Comment: this comes from the array package so `texdoc array` or there are hundreds of examples on this site.

Comment: Ok I watched a video here bfseries
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dLKSsPgEvJE
 so this helped me to understand the use of \bfseries I was not clear what is that about which wikibooks link is talking.